# New Microsoft icon appearing in taskbar when Windows starts-up

Tags: microsoft-office, boot, microsoft-office-2013

What is this and how do I disable it?
[image: screen shot]

I have Windows 7 and Office 2013 installed. I have looked in the registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` but the only entery I couldn't identify was `C:\Program Files\Windows Sidebar\sidebar.exe /autoRun` which doesn't sound like it.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google and Microsoft it's a part of Office itself:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/microsoft-office-upload-center-HA010388348.aspx

The icon can be disabled, according to "Display Options" part